# Offline WorldPress site won't load, what could be the cause?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, xampp, offline

I've got a live site, which I downloaded in order to be able to customize it more precisely by editing the code. I followed the steps of [this tutorial](https://managewp.com/how-to-create-a-local-copy-of-a-live-wordpress-site).

What I've done so far:

1. Downloaded the files of my site.
2. Downloaded its database.
3. Created a new database (with the same name that is included in wp-config file).
4. Imported the downloaded database into the newly created one.
5. Edited the two entries according to step 5 in the tutorial and of course, added a new user with global privileges.
6. Edited the hosts file to have a custom domain.
7. Restarted Apache & MySQL (I use XAMPP).

Now it is still displaying the same error message, that a database connection could not be established.

There is "localhost" set up, but I am not able to use it, I can only connect to my offline sites by using 127.0.0.1.
[image]

I'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: Is DB_HOST set to `localhost`? Did you use the same user in step 5 that is specified in DB_USER/DB_PASSWORD? Did you name the local database according to DB_NAME? Can you connect to mysql locally with those credentials?

Comment: I can only connect with the IP (127.0.0.1), but in phpMyAdmin "localhost" is set up. I think that could be the cause, but I've got no clue how to change it.
I used all the credentianls that were specified in the wp-config file.
How can I connect locally to mySQL? I've never done it before.

I've refreshed my question with a photo.

Comment: `localhost` generally resolves to 127.0.0.1, so that should work just fine. If you can connect with a locally installed phpmyadmin with those credentials, they seem fine (Other tools: mysql commandline client, HeidiSQL etc pp). Is DB_HOST set to localhost in the wp-config.php?

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend, that was the solution. It was still the servers address. :) Now it is working!